# Color scheme based on distro name [linux]

Tags: linux, vim

I use the same vim setting across multiple Linux systems (at the moment Kubuntu and OpenSuse) thanks to `git`. I want to use different color schemes in for the various distros.

So I've create a plugin `plugin/mycolor.vim` where I fetch the distro name from `/etc/os-release` and then use

```
if s:distro ==? "openSUSE" 
   blabla
else
   blabla2
endif
```

The `/etc/os-release` looks like

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.04, Raring Ringtail"
[...]
```

or

```
NAME=openSuse
VERSION="13.1 (Bottle)"
```

The shortest way to get the distro name that I have found (with some help) is

```
let distro = system(". /etc/os-release; echo -n $NAME")
```

but the idea of sourcing the file make be a bit uneasy, although it seems that the sourcing does not propagate outside the call of system.

The other, longer and probably safer way, that I've found is:

```
let s:distro = system("awk '/^NAME=/ {print $1}' /etc/os-release")
let s:distro = split(substitute(s:distro, "\n", "", ""), "=")[1]
let s:distro = substitute(s:distro,'"', "", "g")
```

The first line gets all the line containing `NAME=` included the new line character. The second line remove the new line and return the part after `=`. The third line removes the `"` if any.

Is that any better way to get the distro name or is already stored in some vim variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vim is multi-platform, it tries to avoid platform-specific stuff as much as possible. Therefore, there's no built-in variable; you can only use `has('unix')` to check for a Unixoid operating system in general.

I'd use your first approach with sourcing `/etc/os-release` (calling `lsb_release -is` might work, too); as it only invokes the shell, it's probably a tiny bit more efficient than using AWK to parse. You could also read in the file in Vimscript (via `readfile()`) and do the parsing there, but that just adds additional dependencies to the used syntax.

As a new shell is launched for `system()`, this has no side effects in Vim. Also, since the data file resides under `/etc`, only users with administrative rights are able to change it, so it's no security risk.

#### Alternative

If you have a need for other system-specific Vim configuration (e.g. different window size, or font), an elegant way is to add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Source system-specific .vimrc first.
if filereadable(expand('~/local/.vimrc'))
    source ~/local/.vimrc
endif
```

In that local config file, you can then define a `g:distro` config variable. This duplicates the actual information and requires a bit of manual setup, but would avoid the system call on each Vim startup.

Comment: Great suggestions! I like a lot the **Alternative**, although I would put search the file by default in `~/.local/.vimrc` (on linux). It have the huge advantage to be platform independent (if I'm not wrong). ps: do you know if `lsb_release` is a linux standard or is implemented only in some distros?

Comment: FYI, on my archlinux, `lsb_release` is not installed. @FrancescoMontesano

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have different setting for different computer/system, I am with Ingo. create its own config part, and in your common vimrc source the specific config. I manage my `.zshrc` in this way among three computers.

If you just want to get the string from `/etc/os-release`, you could try:

```
let dis = system("awk -F= '$1==\"ID\"{printf $2}' /etc/os-release")
```

here it prints `arch` (I am running on archlinux).  I picked `ID` instead of `NAME` because the `NAME` could have spaces.

If you like you can try to process the file `/etc/issue`, if all your systems have that file.

Comment: Noth openSUSE and Kubuntu have `/etc/issue` but it's a long string with spaces. Yes, you're right: `ID` make more sense that `NAME`

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano if /etc/issue exists, what i meant is, you could read the content of that file, and take the first column by awk/cut. it is easier than parsing /etc/os-release.

Comment: nope, it's not easier: in openSuse I get: `Welcome to openSUSE 13.1 "Bottle" - kernel \r (\l)`; in Kubuntu: `Ubuntu 13.04 \n \l`